# Transitioning between Android Fragments using a Fragment controller

Tags: android, fragment, state-machine

I am new to Android and I am trying to build an app containing three fragments: let's say A, B, and C. I want a button on A to show me B when clicked, and a button on B to show me C when clicked. I understand that one way is to use FragmentManager like this: in fragment A, I can have a button click listener that does

`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, new B())
    .commit();`

However, I do not want A to know about fragment B, or B to know about C. I was thinking of creating some kind of FragmentController to solve this problem such that the Controller would know about the necessary transitions and maintain a state machine.

Is this a common pattern in Android? I tried googling but I didn't see many code examples for this pattern. How can I decouple the different fragments so that the fragments don't have to worry about the transitions?

Thanks.

Comment: Fragments are attached to an Activity so any kind of transition should happen from the Activity they are going to be attached to.
Have a call back from your fragments to the activity and from the activity attach which ever fragment you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a common pattern, you need understand how to work the comunnication between fragments.

Taking on, your fragments are contained in an activity, maybe you can do the next:

**The Fragment listener**

```
public interface FragmentNavigationListener {
    public void onNavigateTo(int fragment);
}
```

**The Activity which implements callback**

```
public static final int Fragment FRAGMENT_A = 0;
public static final int Fragment FRAGMENT_B = 1;

@Override
public void onNavigateTo(int fragment){
   switch fragment{
      case FRAGMENT_A :
           ...
      case FRAGMENT_B :
           ...
   }
}
```

**Each Fragment** 
must encore that parent activity implements the listener

```
   @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            mCallback = (FragmentNavigationListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement FragmentNavigationListener");
        }
    }
```

In OnclickListener from each button in each fragment you call the listener.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on click   
                   mCallback.onNavigateTo(FRAGMENT_B);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Write fragmentInteraction interfaces, define methods in this interface, then onAttach of the fragment lifeCycle do this

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

That way every activity to which this fragment gets attached to must implement the OnFragmentInteractionListener. Now in your onClick method do `mListener.onClick(view)` assuming you have a method called `onClick(View v)` defined in your interface. And in your activity's implementation of the onClick function do the fragmentTransaction